# how can use torch model?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, torch

I have a **[Torch Model](https://github.com/satoshiiizuka/siggraph2016_colorization)** which is trained on a large scale dataset ([Places Dataset](http://places.csail.mit.edu/)) and it's authors uploaded it on github, i am working on a similar project and i want to make use of it and use it's trained weights instead of use the large dataset to train it and save time and efforts, it is possible ? how can i know the only the trained filters weights? i don't want to copy the code, i only want to make use of it and save time and efforts.

**NOTE:**  I use Tensoflow in my implementation.

Comment: It looks like someone has hand-written a [converter](https://github.com/Cadene/tensorflow-model-zoo.torch/blob/master/inceptionv4/tensorflow_dump.py) into tensorflow for a particular model. You could try to write the same code in reverse for your model.

Comment: thanks for ur reply but can you explain more.@drpng

Comment: I don't know of a simple way to import from Torch, although Keras might have something. The tensorflow format is well [documented](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/tool_developers/), and should be easy to write. You can reverse-engineer how the Torch model is written with `hd5` from the link above, and instead of write, read.

Comment: Maybe you can try to use https://github.com/bshillingford/python-torchfile then just access the `weights` of each layer.

Comment: thanks for you @ManuelLagunas

Comment: I found this tool https://github.com/nerox8664/pytorch2keras. But I didn't try.